# Display List as Multiline Label in TKinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, tkinter-label

I have a Table i am generating using a List (Baseline_Data).

I can get this to print to the terminal fine using:

```
for row in Baseline_Data:
    # Display List as Table
    print('\t'.join(row))
```

What i cant get to work is for this to display in my Tkinter GUI. I found the best way to achieve this would be to generate a label and configure the text.

I have tried:

```
Import_Lab.config(text=("\t".join(row)))
```

Which only displays the last row of my List

```
Import_Lab.config(text=('\n'.join(row)))
```

Which does the same but displays it as a column

```
Import_Lab.config(text=(Baseline_Data))
```

Which displays the full List but as one long continuous line.

How do i display this List as a Multi-line Label ?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

def Import_Button1_Press():

    Baseline_Data = [
    ['     IM      |', 'IM.Ser', 'Maj', 'Min', 'IIB.Ser', 'Maj', 'Min', 'ManfDate'],
    ['---------------------------------------------------------------------------'],
    ['1 - IM1 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['1 - IM2 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['1 - IM3 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['1 - IM4 |', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'],
    ['1 - IM5 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['1 - IM6 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM1 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM2 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM3 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM4 |', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'],
    ['2 - IM5 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM6 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"]
    ]

    for row in Baseline_Data:
        # Display List as Table
        print('\t'.join(row))

Tab1 = ttk.Frame(note)

canvas1 = Canvas(Tab1, width=550, height=350)
canvas1.pack()

Tab2 = ttk.Frame(note)

canvas2 = Canvas(Tab2, width=550, height=350)
canvas2.pack()

Import_Button1 = tk.Button(Tab2, text = 'Import XML [Baseline]', width=25, height=2, command=Import_Button1_Press)
Import_Button_Window = canvas2.create_window(25, 40, anchor = 'w', window = Import_Button1)

Import_Lab = Label(Tab2, anchor=W)
Import_Lab_Window = canvas2.create_window(275, 175, anchor = 'center', window = Import_Lab)

note.add(Tab1, text = " Main ")
note.add(Tab2, text = " Baseline Data ")

note.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate the complete string, with all the lines (rows of the table) and then pass it to the `text` argument, for example:

```
Import_Lab.config(text="\n".join("\t".join(row) for row in Baseline_Data))
```

For the table to display correctly, **use a monospace font for that label**.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def import_button1_press():

    baseline_data = [
        ['     IM      |', 'IM.Ser', 'Maj', 'Min', 'IIB.Ser', 'Maj', 'Min', 'ManfDate'],
        ['---------------------------------------------------------------------------'],
        ['1 - IM1 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['1 - IM2 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['1 - IM3 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['1 - IM4 |',       'NA', 'NA', 'NA',    'NA', 'NA', 'NA',     'NA'],
        ['1 - IM5 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['1 - IM6 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM1 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM2 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM3 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM4 |',       'NA', 'NA', 'NA',    'NA', 'NA', 'NA',     'NA'],
        ['2 - IM5 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM6 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"]
    ]
    
    table = "\n".join("\t".join(row) for row in baseline_data)
    import_lab.config(text=table)


root = tk.Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(note)

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(tab1, width=850, height=650)
canvas1.pack()

tab2 = ttk.Frame(note)

canvas2 = tk.Canvas(tab2, width=850, height=650)
canvas2.pack()

import_button1 = tk.Button(
    tab2, text='Import XML [Baseline]',
    width=25, height=2,
    command=import_button1_press
    )
import_button_window = canvas2.create_window(
    25, 40, anchor='w', window=import_button1
    )

import_lab = tk.Label(tab2, font=('Consolas', 10), justify=tk.LEFT, anchor='nw')
import_lab_window = canvas2.create_window(
    425, 350, anchor='center', window=import_lab
    )

note.add(tab1, text=" Main ")
note.add(tab2, text=" Baseline Data ")

note.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]
Another option to generate plain text tables easily is to use the [tabulate package](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/):

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def import_button1_press():

    baseline_data = [
        ['     IM      |', 'IM.Ser', 'Maj', 'Min', 'IIB.Ser', 'Maj', 'Min', 'ManfDate'],
        ['---------------------------------------------------------------------------'],
        ['1 - IM1 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['1 - IM2 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['1 - IM3 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['1 - IM4 |',       'NA', 'NA', 'NA',    'NA', 'NA', 'NA',     'NA'],
        ['1 - IM5 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['1 - IM6 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM1 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM2 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM3 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM4 |',       'NA', 'NA', 'NA',    'NA', 'NA', 'NA',     'NA'],
        ['2 - IM5 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
        ['2 - IM6 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"]
    ]

    table = tabulate(
        baseline_data[2:], headers=baseline_data[0], tablefmt="fancy_grid"
        )
    import_lab.config(text=table)


root = tk.Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(note)

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(tab1, width=850, height=650)
canvas1.pack()

tab2 = ttk.Frame(note)

canvas2 = tk.Canvas(tab2, width=850, height=650)
canvas2.pack()

import_button1 = tk.Button(
    tab2, text='Import XML [Baseline]',
    width=25, height=2,
    command=import_button1_press
    )
import_button_window = canvas2.create_window(
    25, 40, anchor='w', window=import_button1
    )

import_lab = tk.Label(tab2, font=('Consolas', 8), justify=tk.LEFT, anchor='nw')
import_lab_window = canvas2.create_window(
    425, 325, anchor='center', window=import_lab
    )

note.add(tab1, text=" Main ")
note.add(tab2, text=" Baseline Data ")

note.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Tabulate definitely looks like a sleeker solution, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Label` inside Import_Lab_Window with an empty text. On clicking the `Button`, the function Import_Button1_Press() which configures the label-text with the data given. To display data displayed as lines, add '\n' to every end of the line.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *



def Import_Button1_Press():

    Baseline_Data = [
    ['     IM      |', 'IM.Ser', 'Maj', 'Min', 'IIB.Ser', 'Maj', 'Min', 'ManfDate'],
    ['---------------------------------------------------------------------------'],
    ['1 - IM1 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['1 - IM2 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['1 - IM3 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['1 - IM4 |', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'],
    ['1 - IM5 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['1 - IM6 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM1 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM2 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM3 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM4 |', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'],
    ['2 - IM5 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"],
    ['2 - IM6 |',    "12345", "22", "33", "12345", "55", "66", "123456"]
    ]

    for row in Baseline_Data:
        # Display List as Table
        data = '\n'.join(row)
        lbl.configure(text = data)
        
        
root = Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)
Tab1 = ttk.Frame(note)

canvas1 = Canvas(Tab1, width=550, height=350)
canvas1.pack()

Tab2 = ttk.Frame(note)

canvas2 = Canvas(Tab2, width=550, height=350)
canvas2.pack()

Import_Button1 = tk.Button(Tab2, text = 'Import XML [Baseline]', width=25, height=2, command=Import_Button1_Press)
Import_Button_Window = canvas2.create_window(25, 40, anchor = 'w', window = Import_Button1)

Import_Lab = Label(Tab2, anchor=W)
Import_Lab_Window = canvas2.create_window(275, 175, anchor = 'center', window = Import_Lab)

#Add lbl inside Import_Lab_Window

lbl = Label(Import_Lab_Window, text = '')
lbl.pack()



note.add(Tab1, text = " Main ")
note.add(Tab2, text = " Baseline Data ")

note.pack()
root.mainloop()
```